# passing href querystring values to an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass the values from the `ul#ignorelist.userlist li > a` into an array called arr. But i dont need the whole href, i just need the userID.

*Something like this: 14301, 65958*

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="userlist floatcontainer" id="ignorelist">
    <li id="user14301"><input checked="checked" id="usercheck_14301" name=
    "listbits[ignore][14301]" type="checkbox" value="14301"><a href=
    "member.php?u=14301">Frenchy</a><input name=
    "listbits[ignore_original][14301]" type="hidden" value="14301"></li>

    <li id="user65958"><input checked="checked" id="usercheck_65958" name=
    "listbits[ignore][65958]" type="checkbox" value="65958"><a href=
    "member.php?u=65958">GermanMan</a><input name=
    "listbits[ignore_original][65958]" type="hidden" value="65958"></li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery:**

```
var arr = $('ul#ignorelist.userlist li > a').map(function() {
return this;
}).toArray();
```

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7dWFN/13/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, note that you don't need `toArray`, `map` method returns an array.

```
var arr = $('#ignorelist.userlist li').map(function() {
      return this.id.match(/\d+/g).join('')
      // or return this.id.replace('user', '')
}).get()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6aP7W/

```
var names = $('#ignorelist.userlist li a').map(function() {
      return $(this).text()
}).get()
```

Comment: also can you tell me how to get the string value into the array, eg:
["Frenchy", "GermanMAN"]

Comment: @SOLDIER-OF-FORTUNE I have updated the answer, for sake of performance, you can cache the objects. `var $li = $('#ignorelist.userlist li')` for first map `$li.map()....` second: `$li.find('a').map()`